# How do I call a method from a Form class?

Tags: c#, mysql

Right now I have this code in a class called HelperClass:

```
class HelperClass : CollegeSystem.GUI
    {

        public void selectStudent()
        {
             MySqlConnection conn; // connection object;
        string connstring = "server=localhost;user Id=root;database=collegesystem;Convert Zero Datetime=True ";

            try
            {
                conn = new MySqlConnection(connstring);
                conn.Open();
                MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM person", conn);
                MySqlDataReader myReader;
                myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                cmbTable.Items.Clear();
                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    cmbTable.Items.Add(myReader["personID"] + " | " + myReader["firstName"] + " | " + myReader["lastName"] + " | " + myReader["address"] + " | " + myReader["phoneNumber"] + " | " + myReader["postCode"] + " | " + myReader["dateOfBirth"]);
                }
            }

            catch (Exception err)
            {//handle the error with a message
                lblInfo.Text = " Error reading the database.";
                lblInfo.Text += err.Message; ;
            }

            finally
            {

            }
```

And I would like to call that from my form, but it doesn't work:

```
 private void fillcomboBox()
 {
     selectStudent();
 }
```

The name "selectStudent" does not exist in the current context

I have placed this at the top of the form:

```
 public partial class GUI : Form, College_System.HelperClass
```

am I missing something?

PS. Why would the `cmbTable` and `lblInfo` be inaccessible due to it's protection level?
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe `HelperClass.selectStudent();`.

Comment: With that, "HelperClass" does not exist in the current context

Comment: Sorry it's wrong, your class `HelperClass` inherits from `CollegeSystem.GUI` and
`GUI` from `College_System.HelperClass`? Is correct the namespace `College_System` ?

Comment: You can't have multiple inheritance in C#, does `CollegeSystem.GUI` inherit from form?

Comment: Ok, so instead of `CollegeSystem.GUI`
Im using this
`using CollegeSystem;`
But, It still cant find
`private void fillcomboBox()
 {
     selectStudent();
 }`

Comment: I'll add an answer in about an hour when I can... you are mixing a lot of concepts here. What does `CollegeSystem.GUI` inherit from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple issues with this code.

1. You have a class and an instance method, and you are calling the method directly. You should create instance of the class and call the method.
2. Check if the class definition and call are in same namespace or not. If not, you should define the class as internal/public and include the namespace in the calling code page.
3. You can't access the label unless they are defined in the same class (the helper)

In general, helper classes are standalone classes, where you pass the data to its methods and get result for processing. For instance, you can try something like:

```
class myForm : Form
{
    protected void OnClick()
    {
        try
        {
            var data = Helper.SelectStudent();
            cmbTable.Items.AddRange(data);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblInfo.Text = " Error reading the database.";
            lblInfo.Text += err.Message; ;
        }
    }
}

class HelperClass
{
    public static List<string> SelectStudent()
    {
        List<string> data = new List<string>();
        MySqlConnection conn; // connection object;
        string connstring = "server=localhost;user Id=root;database=collegesystem;Convert Zero Datetime=True ";
        conn = new MySqlConnection(connstring);
        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM person", conn);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
        cmbTable.Items.Clear();
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            data.Add(myReader["personID"] + " | " + myReader["firstName"] + " | " + myReader["lastName"] + " | " + myReader["address"] + " | " + myReader["phoneNumber"] + " | " + myReader["postCode"] + " | " + myReader["dateOfBirth"]);
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: `public static DataTable SelectStudent()
        {
            try
            {
                //...
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }`

I dont understand what I am supposed to place there

Comment: the connectionstring, the datareader, while loop (that create the datatable). Before catch block, you should return the datatable created through the while loop. You can even remove the try...catch block in SelectStudent as the same available in OnClick.

Comment: `public static DataTable SelectStudent()`

why would that give an error `not all code paths return a value`

by that I mean the `SelectStudent()`

Comment: I have updated the code. Though I haven't compiled the code, it should be better now.

Comment: wow thank you for that, Im getting a much better idea about this now, however, just a few kinks try 
`{ var data = HelperClass.SelectStudent(); cmbTable.Items.AddRange(data); }`
by `Helper` I think you mean `HelperClass` but this is saying that it does not exist in the current context, and same for `cmbTable` in the HelperClass

but again, thank you

Comment: Yeah, its a typo. You can mark it as answer, if it answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

By default the attribute are private. If you want use in herited classe you can choice : public protected,conteneur,protectedinternal

In your case i suggest public

```
 public class HelperClass : CollegeSystem.GUI
```

Answer (score 1):

> public partial class GUI : Form, College_System.HelperClass

you can't do this. Your line

```
public partial class GUI : Form, College_System.HelperClass
```

should be

```
public partial class GUI : Form
```

then you can call like

```
College_System.HelperClass c = new College_System.HelperClass();
c.selectStudent();
```

Comment: ok...so with `College_System.HelperClass.selectStudent();` I get no error, now my error is still that those are inaccessible AND `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property`

Comment: that happens for each time i have `cmbTable` or `lblInfo`

Comment: You appear to be putting *all* of your code into this helper class. You are getting the error because `cmbTable` is probably something from your original form. Make your code just return a list of `Person`'s (make a class for it). Leave all the `cmbTable.Items.Add....` stuff in your main form code.

Comment: the updated answer now gives another error:
`c.selectStudent();`
`'College_System.HelperClass.selectStudent()' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead`

Comment: @Arran do you mind showing me what you mean, I think I understand but I have already waste a lot of time on this, so I dont want to waste another hour fumbling around.

Comment: you have made selectStudent() as static? if so remove the static keyword and it would work.